# Register new memer for vBulletin via Mobile API

Tags: vbulletin

I'm trying to use the vBulletin REST Mobile API to simply register.
The sourced are installed on my local machine and according  the documentation https://www.vbulletin.com/forum/content.php/393-User-Registration-Process-Mobile-API

This procedure should not be so hard, especially without humanity and COPPA authentication.
However I've stacked!
The method definition describes "addnewmember" clear, so I've generated a test link, which should do the job.
https://www.vbulletin.com/forum/content.php/365-User-Related-Methods

The link is: 
 .../forum/api.php?&api_m=register_addmember&api_c=1&api_s=76ec9eec61e7fdfef2f3feee28d5f392&api_sig=8fe54313b333cc0fef4ddd8e398b5c80&api_v=6&agree=1&username=testuser&email=XXXXXX%40gmail.com&emailconfirm=XXXXX%40gmail.com&password=12345678&passwordconfirm=12345678

As a response I get: register_not_agreed

The Docs: register_not_agreed
The agree parameter should be set to 1.

Which is also clear - agree parameter was not there.
Here comes the funny part - In the API-Log I can see that the 'agree' parameter is correctly passed 
    *1  test_client     Gast    13:23, 18.06.2012   register_addmember  Array ( [api_m] => register_addmember [api_c] => 1 [api_s] => 76ec9eec61e7fdfef2f3feee28d5f392 [api_sig] => 8fe54313b333cc0fef4ddd8e398b5c80 [api_v] => 6 [agree] => 1 [username] => testuser [email] => ....*

Is there anybody with experience with the Mobile API that could help?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it does not work with a pure GET call but I'm sure it will work (because I'm working on a vBulletin API client in Python and I did it this way) if you:

- use GET parameters to send `api_c`, `api_sm`, `api_m`, and `api_sig`
- use POST data for all the rest (username, email, agree, etc)